# SearchManager functionality - Icon on the left of the search bar

Tags: android

I am trying to use the `SearchManager` - it works ok but the icon I am specifying in the searchable.xml is not appearing on the bar instead the default "green android" button is showing up. I removed the icon line from `searchable.xml` but the "green android" button still shows up. What am I doing wrong here?

```
android:searchSuggestAuthority="xyz"
android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://xyz/favorites" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the icon to put it there. It takes the Application icon as the default.
You must have set the application icon as the green icon.